# How to make Firefox stop suggesting if I meant to go a website when I search

Tags: firefox

I search using the URL address bar in Firefox however when I search a phrase or whatever a popup always comes up asking " Did you mean to go to *example*? ". It's quite annoying and was wondering if it could be turned off. I don't use the other search bar because whenever I click on it or try to use it an ugly panel comes down with the engines I can search with. Even if I turn off all other search engines it still persists.

Answer (score 3):

It seems we will be able disable this new feature via about:config in Firefox 36: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1088050

For now you can add this line:

```
notification[value="keyword-uri-fixup"] { display: none !important; }
```

to the userChrome.css inside the chrome subfolder of your Firefox profile folder. If userChrome.css doesn't exist there, create it: http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome-example.css

Or, alternatively, you can use the Stylish add-on and create a new user style like this:

```
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);
notification[value="keyword-uri-fixup"] { display: none !important; }
```

Comment: What about for Chrome/Chromium as I learned it also occurs in those browsers?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to your ISP providing you with a poorly-configured DNS server, as per [this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/a/266053/11574) about Chrome, which behaves similarly:

> Your DNS is taking that word and telling Chrome that its a website. So
>   Chrome asks you if you meant to visit it. Chances are, if you did
>   visit that site, you'd end up on your ISP's not found page.
>
> The only way I've found to rectify this is turning off the "web
>   service" option in the options and changing your DNS to [a better DNS
>   provider].

Answer (score 1):

switch your DNS from the default provided by your ISP to Google DNS:

"The Google Public DNS IP addresses (IPv4) are as follows:

8.8.8.8

8.8.4.4"

https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#setup

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the suggestions, go to *Firefox Preferences* and click on the *Privacy* tab.

Under the *Location Bar* setting at the bottom, select the *Nothing* option from the drop down menu to disable all suggestions.

Comment: I've already done that, it did nothing except take away the panel that tumbles down from the URL bar as you're typing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the [Mozilla docs](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1129065) worked for me:

> You can set browser.urlbar.unifiedcomplete to false to remove the
>   Visit page suggestion from the location bar drop down list.
>
> You can open the about:config page via the location/address bar. You
>   can accept the warning and click "I'll be careful" to continue.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this is to re-configure your computer's DNS settings to use a dedicated service rather than your ISP's default DNS. Depending on your setup, this may also have positive side-effects with regard to your internet speed, security, ad-blocking, etc.

On Windows 10:

- Open the Control Panel.
- Select "Network and Internet."
- Select "Network and Sharing Center."
- Under "View your active networks," click on the name of your network interface (for example, the name of your Wi-Fi network or "Ethernet" for a wired connection).
- In the pop-up window, select "Properties."
- Select "Internet Protocol Version 4" and then click "Properties" again in this new pop-up window.
- Instead of "Obtain DNS server address automatically," select "Use the following DNS server addresses" and enter the IP address(es) belonging to your chosen DNS provider.
- Also update "Internet Protocol Version 6" in the same manner.

[image: Windows 10 DNS Settings]

---

On Mac OS:

- Open System Preferences.
- Select "Network."
- Select your internet network interface (Wi-Fi, Ethernet, etc.), and then click the "Advanced" button.
- Under the DNS tab, use the "+" button to add the IP addresses belonging to your chosen DNS provider, the "-" button to remove existing ones, and drag-and-drop to adjust the order if necessary.
- Click "OK" in the Advanced pop-up window and then "Apply" in the main Network settings panel.

[image: Mac OS DNS Settings]

---

For advanced users, it might be worth doing a bit of research to decide which provider is best for your needs. For everyone else, just use one of these.

Cloudflare:

- Primary DNS (IPv4): 1.1.1.1
- Secondary DNS (IPv4): 1.0.0.1
- Primary DNS (IPv6): 2606:4700:4700::1111
- Secondary DNS (IPv6): 2606:4700:4700::1001

Google DNS:

- Primary DNS (IPv4): 8.8.8.8
- Secondary DNS (IPv4): 8.8.4.4
- Primary DNS (IPv6): 2001:4860:4860::8888
- Secondary DNS (IPv6): 2001:4860:4860::8844

OpenDNS:

- Primary DNS (IPv4): 208.67.222.222
- Secondary DNS (IPv4): 208.67.220.220
- Primary DNS (IPv6): 2620:119:35::35
- Secondary DNS (IPv6): 2620:119:53::53